# OnPropertyChanged is null in WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, null, viewmodel, icommand

**AcctionCommand**

> My problem is that for the change of the variable are reflected in the user interface, the value of PropertyChanged should be different from null (Left) because I'm assigning a value.

I have a generic class to handle the click events of the buttons

```
 public class ActionCommand : ICommand
{
    Action action;
    public ActionCommand(Action action)
    {
        this.action = action;
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        action();
    }
}
```

**INotifyPropertyChanged**
I have a class NotificationEnabledObject to notify the Left value change to the user interface in PropertyChange which always returns null,  I do not know what I'm doing wrong??

```
  public class NotificationEnabledObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}
```

**ViewModel**
I have a ViewModel class that has the Left property.

```
public class WordsViewModel : NotificationEnabledObject
{

    string left;
    public string Left
    {
        get { return left; }
        set
        {
            left = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }

    }
```

> MainPage.xaml

```
   <phone:PhoneApplicationPage
        x:Class="SpeechRecognition.MainPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
        xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:core="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
        FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
        Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
        SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
          xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:SpeechRecognition.ViewModels"
        shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
      DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}">

       <StackPanel>

                       <Grid Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                  <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" FontSize="40" x:Name="txtWord" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="center">
                       <core:Run x:Name="rLeft" Text="{Binding Left, Mode=TwoWay}" />                                    
                        </TextBlock>
                            <Button Name="ReadNow" Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto" Content="Read Now" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="ReadNow_Click">

                            </Button>

                        </Grid>     

            </StackPanel>



    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

> This action is the click event of the button on the user interface, I do not know how to make this work, OnPropertyChanged is always null, I want to change the value of the variable in interface Left repeatedly while running the program

```
    ActionCommand getWordsCommand;
    public ActionCommand GetWordsCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (getWordsCommand == null)
            {
                getWordsCommand = new ActionCommand(() =>
                    {  
                       Left = 10;
                    }
                });
            }

           return getWordsCommand;
          }
```

}

Comment: Just a suggestion - I would make the question itself a little clearer and put it at the top.  It takes a little looking to find what you are actually asking.

Comment: @user3453659 Please review the answer below and either respond to it or upvote and select it if it works for you.

Comment: thanks for your answer is very usefull,... i'm working in the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems

First, your data context needs to be set in your view code behind

```
this.Datacontext = //your view model
```

Second, Your WordsViewModel class needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Third your `OnPropertyChanged` Signature is wrong.

It should look like the below example

Also you shouldn't be using your actual PropertChanged event handler. Its not thread safe.

Instead, clone it within your `OnPropertyChanged` event

```
void OnPropertyChanged(String prop){
 PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
 if(handler != null){
   PropertChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
 }

}
```

Finally in your `Left` property invoke `OnPropertyChanged("Left");`

Comment: thanks for your answer is very usefull,...  i'm working in the solution